# Multithreading - Spawn multiple threads and wait

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need some advice on multithreading.

Example: I want to spawn 200 Threads, each one should grab one different image from an website (the site is kinda slow). But there should be max. 40 Threads at once.

Any idea?

I look forward to some answers.

Comment: Take a look at the .NET 4.0 Task Parallel Library.

Comment: Indeed, use the TPL (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx). Where does the 40 come from? Let the TPL scheduling mechanism decide how many concurrent tasks will be running, its quite good.

Comment: The 40 an 200 are variables, which the user can enter. I will have a look at the tpl, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use `ThreadPool` for this. The pool does a good job of managing threads but if you *really really* must limit the maximum number you can use:

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(40, 40);

// submit 200 tasks to the pool
for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
       () =>
       {
           // code for each task
       });
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no built-in way to wait for the tasks to finish so you'll just have to improvise something. If you have access to .NET 4.0 you can check out `Parallel.For`:

```
ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 40;
Parallel.For(0, 200, po,
   i =>
   {
      // code for each task
   });
```

Comment: I was going to make the same answer... For the ThreadPool he could use a callback function with a context parameter that holds the information about the specific thread.

Answer (score 1):

Use a thread-safe queue, filled with all the URLs you want.

Create 40 threads whose job is to take the next item from that queue and download from the URL. When the queue is empty the threads should finish.

Comment: It seems easier to just use the `ThreadPool` class, since it encapsulates all the above mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SlimSemaphore slm=new SlimSemaphore(40);

slm.Wait()

[your code]

slm.Release();
```

This will allow only 40 threads to execute at a time.

Note: SlimSemaphore (if using .Net framework 4.0)
      else
      Semaphore

```
 only efficiency difference is there
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set MaxDegreeParallelism using a ParallelOptions object you create and supply to a Parallel.ForEach loop.I will paste some code when I am behind a proper keyboard again later.